# how to get the number of times each value of a CGPoint array is repeated

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filtering

I have the an array of `CGPoint`s,

```
pointArray = [(532.7, 150.0), (66.6, 150.0), (129.2, 150.0), (129.2, 150.0), (301.2, 150.0), (444.2, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0)]
```

How can I get the number of times each point is repeated?

Comment: Have a look at `NSCountedSet`

Comment: @LeoDabus So make it Hashable :)

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure it is. It's already been done for you by Martin :)

Comment: @LeoDabus Well it would appear you would need it now. Converting CGPoints into strings to use as keys in a dictionary is, in effect, a really crappy hashing algorithm. Just swap it out with a better designed one, like what martin posted, and use the same algorithm as you currently are

Comment: @LeoDabus What would work fine for most situations?

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Alexander I am a bit lost here

Comment: Strange, Leo deleted everything he had posted here. I'll answer this question when I have time later

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, I'll most definitely be waiting for your answer, though I hope it comes sooner than later :)

Comment: @LeoDabus No need, Rodrigo Ruiz Murguía already nailed it

Comment: @LeoDabus No, I would use a hash function like the one you linked to in the code review SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alexander has said in comments, you should use a `NSCountedSet` you can use it like this:

```
let array = [
    CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 66.6, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 129.2, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 129.2, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 301.2, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 444.2, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0),
    CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0)
]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: array)
countedSet.count(for: array.last!) //returns 4
```

If you do not wish to use `NSCountedSet`, you can store each point on a dictionary as key, and the count as value. The tricky thing is that `CGPoint` does not conform to `Hashable`, you could do it like this:

```
extension CGPoint:Hashable{
    public var hashValue: Int {
        let x = Double(self.x)
        let y = Double(self.y)

        return Int(((x + y)*(x + y + 1)/2) + y)
        //this hash function may not be the best for your data

    }
}

var map = [CGPoint:Int]()
for point in array {
    if let count = map[point] {
        map[point] = count + 1
    } else {
        map[point] = 1
    }
}

map[array.last!]//returns 4
```

I think it is better to use a `NSCountedSet`

Comment: `NSCountedSet` needs `Hashable` as well. The trick behind the scenes is that the values are converted to `NSValue`, I believe.

Comment: `NSCountedSet` has two initializers:
`public convenience init(array: [Any])` and
`public convenience init(set: Set<AnyHashable>)`

You only need `Hashable` passing a `Set` to `init`
(I'm using Swift 3.0.2 with Xcode 8.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

I think the use of CountedSet is overkill. I would just count them:

```
let points = [CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 66.6, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 129.2, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 129.2, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 301.2, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 444.2, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0), CGPoint(x: 532.7, y: 150.0)]
var d : [NSValue:Int] = [:]
for p in points {
    let v = NSValue(cgPoint:p)
    if let ct = d[v] {
        d[v] = ct+1
    } else {
        d[v] = 1
    }
}
// how many times does `points[0]` appear in `points`?
d[NSValue(cgPoint:points[0])] // 4
```

Comment: Thats the best approach in my opinion. You can also make CGPoint Hashable returning its corresponding NSValue hashValue

Comment: Just note that you could just cast from CGPoint to NSValue instead of creating a new object

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, I think that's brand new in Swift 3.0.1 and I'm still not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with matt that the accepted solutions seem like overkill. I'd suggest a similar approach to the one he took, but using a functional style:

```
let dictionary:[String:Int] = array.reduce([:]){
    var dict = $0.0, key = String(describing: $0.1)
    dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? 0 ) + 1
    return dict
}
```

Using this approach, with your original array, we get a result like this:

```
let pointArray:[(CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [(532.7, 150.0), (66.6, 150.0), (129.2, 150.0), (129.2, 150.0), (301.2, 150.0), (444.2, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0), (532.7, 150.0)]

let dictionary:[String:Int] = pointArray.reduce([:]){
    var dict = $0.0, key = String(describing: $0.1)
    dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? 0 ) + 1
    return dict
}

print(dictionary)  //output is ["(129.2, 150.0)": 2, "(66.6, 150.0)": 1, "(532.7, 150.0)": 4, "(444.2, 150.0)": 1, "(301.2, 150.0)": 1]
```

Note that using `String(describing:)` as the dictionary key allows this to work with tuples as in your example code, and other variations that aren't necessarily `CGPoint` or `Hashable` instances. This will give you a `Hashable` key for the dictionary without needing to write custom code; **however, as Alexander points out in the comments below, it is not the most performant way to generate a `Hashable` value, and if you are operating on tens of thousands of points or more, or running this operation frequently in a loop, the difference between using `String(describing:)` vs. a custom function to generate a hash from your point tuples could be significant**

Comment: Using `String(describing:)` as a hashing technique is needlessly expensive and collision-prone

Comment: @Alexander  In general, yes.  In this case, with his array of `(CGFloat, CGFloat)` values, it shouldn't collide and you can't make tuples `Hashable`. Using a `Hashable` extension on `CGPoint`, or wrapping `CGPoint`s in `NSValue` are implementations that can be substituted in other cases, but this answer provides: 1) a functional style for the algorithm 2) a solution that works with the OP's example input, neither of which were covered by previous answers

Comment: Of course it will cause collisions. You're representing the 2 `Int`s of `CGPoint` with a 1 `Int` `hashValue`. There don't exist any functions that can map those 1:1. Your algorithm is good, but it would be much better with a proper hash function defined for `CGPoint` rather than using `String(describing:)`

Comment: @Alexander `CGPoint` doesn't consist of `Int`s and the OP example code isn't using `CGPoint` at all anyway; it's using tuples of `Float`s / `Double`s.  There is no way to create a `Hashable` extension on a tuple, and `String(describing:)` outputs a `String` which is unique for every unique combination of `Float`s in a tuple and will not collide with the hashes of `String` values from other combinations. If you look at the printed output in my example code you will see the `String` keys. None of those will collide with each other unless `String` has a terrible hash implementation (it doesn't)

Comment: I misspoke, I meant that you can't represent 2 64-bit values (`Double`s) with a 1 `Int` hashValue. You *must* have collisions, so it's best you use a hashing algorithm that keeps them as infrequent as possible for the domain of the data being hashed. `String(describing:) outputs a String which is unique for every unique combination of Floats in a tuple` That's correct. ` and will not collide with the hashes of String values from other combinations.` That is not. There are more possible strings than unique hash values. By the pigeonhole theorem, collisions are unavoidable.

Comment: @Alexander Right, makes sense that there are more combinations of two 64-bit values than a single `Int` hash can represent. But that problem exists for any hashing algorithm given same input. So when dealing with an array of `(Float, Float)` tuples, that leaves two options: 1) Use an existing hash algorithm in the standard library, like `String`'s 2) Implement a domain specific hashing function for a `(Float, Float)` with custom code. I'm guessing the real-world difference in collisions would be < 1% for OP's use case. Either option will collide _rarely_; second option seems overkill

Comment: Each tuple will require a dynamic allocation on the heap to contain the String's buffer. For any non-trivial number of tuples, there will be a compelling performance benefit in implementing a simple hash function yourself. Especially on mobile devices, one of the main targets of Swift.

Comment: @Alexander That's a good point that `String` allocations are more costly than some other value types, so an optimized hash function that returns `Int` hashes directly to use as dictionary keys would certainly perform better. Again, based on the original question, I don't think an answer with a custom hashing function is really in scope, but I did update my answer to note the performance caveat if the OP is doing this operation on large data sets or in a loop.